# Asset Pipeline not compiling png files on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, cedar

Found a strange bug in Ruby on Rails 4.1 asset pipeline on Heroku. All of my PNG images are not being compiled.

In Development:

```rb
image_tag('icons/example.png')
# => "/assets/icons/example-09adfasdfa7sfhpasodfuahsdas.png"
```

In Production on Heroku

```rb
image_tag('icons/example.png')
# => "/images/icons/example.png"
```

I have never run across anything like this in the asset pipeline. Any ideas as to why?

**Update**

As it turns out, it's not PNG images in particular. It is any image accessed via `image_tag`. Any images that are precompiled in CSS and Javascript point to the proper paths, but any views/helpers that use `image_tag` (and thus `path_to_image`) are pointing to the `/images`. I cannot tell if this has to do with the `serve_static_assets` configuration that Heroku recommends that is not playing well with Rails 4.1

Comment: Are you using rails_12factor gem? That usually sorts out most issues

Comment: I am. I also have the 'serve_static_assets' configuration set per all of the documentation on Heroku. Still no dice.

Comment: As a follow up, it turns out only PNGs in nested directories are missed on Heroku. Something like `image_tag("header.png")` compiles, but `image_tag("icons/header.png")` does not compile.

Comment: ah yes - you don't need the directory - the asset pipeline does magic when it's running in production mode.

Comment: The asset pipeline only flattens the directories once. Nested images normally aren't an issue in the asset pipeline. The whole purpose is to allow me to organize everything how I see fit. But here it is definitely a factor in it's failure.

Comment: Also, this does not happen when I run in production mode locally. `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails s` after precompiling assets works like a charm. This only seems to break on Heroku.